# Is there a way to see who has earned at least 200 reputation today?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit

I can see in "Users" tab you have groups for `week, month, quarter, year, all`, but no `day`. Is there a way to see which users have reached 200 reputation today?

Comment: You can on Sundays :)

Comment: The last edit kinda changes the meaning of the original question... Rep cap isn't the same as earning 200 rep as explained by Catija in her answer.

Answer (score 10):

Even considering the answer by Nick, this would be a somewhat difficult thing to ever actually deliver because, one could argue, that what Nick says *isn't* particularly true.

You're asking to know who has "rep capped"... and that is not the same as knowing who has earned at least 200 reputation in a given day. We must remember that getting accepted answers, bounties and the association bonus all can cause daily rep to be much more than the reputation cap and, as it is possible for someone to win a Quidditch match without catching the Golden Snitch, so too is it possible for someone to earn thousands of rep in a day and still not rep cap - it's not particularly likely, but it is possible.

So, to answer your very specific question, **no, there is no way to see who has hit the rep cap on any given day, Monday or otherwise**.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, we provide a mechanism to do this, but it only works on Mondays.

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained *how* to use the feature. As it is, this is little more than a comment.

Comment: ... @RobertColumbia It's just by looking at the /users page on a Monday and look at the week view - https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week It's not "last seven days", it's Monday to Sunday, every week.

Comment: @Catija that doesn't seem to be what the OP is asking. The OP is asking for something that works every day. Your solution is more one of those "a broken clock is right twice a day" solutions.

Comment: ... yes, I suppose that's the joke.